# SwiftUI lockscreen widget Gauge accessoryCircular modifier how to set value to empty like weather 0% Precipitation probability

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, widget, lockscreenwidget

I tried set value to 0, -1, and 999999, and didn't work.
My code:

```
Gauge(
   value: -1,
   label: { Text("label") },
   currentValueLabel: { Text("4") },
   minimumValueLabel: { Text("9") },
   maximumValueLabel: { Text("30") }
)
.gaugeStyle(.accessoryCircular)
```

Result:
[image]

And I want to:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried setting a `ClosedRange`? See this https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/gauge/init(value:in:label:currentvaluelabel:minimumvaluelabel:maximumvaluelabel:markedvaluelabels:)

Answer (score 0):

```
struct CustomGaugeStyle: GaugeStyle {
    let lineWidth: Double = 5.5
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ZStack {
                Circle()
                    .trim(from: 0, to: 0.75)
                    .stroke(Color(.lightGray).opacity(0.5), style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: lineWidth, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round))
                    .rotationEffect(.degrees(135))
                
                Circle()
                    .trim(from: -0.3, to: 0.75 * configuration.value)
                    .stroke(Color.orange.gradient, style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: lineWidth, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round))
                    .rotationEffect(.degrees(135))
                configuration.currentValueLabel
                configuration.label
                    .offset(y: 20)
            }
        }
        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
    }
}

struct CustomCircleView: View {
    @State private var innerRingFill = 50.0
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Gauge(value: innerRingFill, in: 0...100) {
                Image(systemName: "gauge.medium")                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .frame(width: 20, height: 15)
            } currentValueLabel: {
                Text("\(innerRingFill.formatted(.number))")
                    .font(.system(size: 17))
            }
            .frame(width: 53, height: 53)
            .gaugeStyle(CustomCircleView())
        }
    }
}
```

[Result of code running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFl9N.png)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more flexible solution that does not use GeometryReader and has the correct insets so the circles are not cut off on the sides. Plus, it uses the tint color.

[image]

```
struct CustomProgressGaugeStyle: GaugeStyle {
    let lineWidth: CGFloat = 6
    
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
            ZStack {
                Circle()
                    .trim(from: 0, to: 0.75)
                    .stroke(
                        .tint.opacity(0.4),
                        style: .init(lineWidth: lineWidth, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round)
                    )
                    .rotationEffect(.degrees(135))

                Circle()
                    .trim(from: -0.3, to: 0.75 * configuration.value)
                    .stroke(
                        .tint,
                        style: .init(lineWidth: lineWidth, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round)
                    )
                    .rotationEffect(.degrees(135))
                
                configuration.currentValueLabel
                    .padding(.horizontal, lineWidth)
            }
            .padding(lineWidth/2)
            .overlay(alignment: .bottom) {
                configuration.label
                    .padding(.horizontal, lineWidth * 2)
            }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var body: some View {
        Gauge(
            value: 0.25,
            label: {
                Label(
                    title: { Text("Umbrella") },
                    icon: { Image(systemName: "umbrella.fill") }
                )
                .labelStyle(.iconOnly)
                .bold()
                .foregroundStyle(tintColor)
                .font(.caption)
            },
            currentValueLabel: {
                Text("50%")
                    .font(.title)
                    .lineLimit(1)
                    .minimumScaleFactor(0.33)
            }
        )
        .gaugeStyle(CustomProgressGaugeStyle())
        .labelStyle(.iconOnly)
        .tint(.blue)
    }
```

Comment: `Type 'CustomProgressGaugeStyle' does not conform to protocol 'GaugeStyle'`, also some errors on "configuration"